# What is the minimum number of squares to be drawn on a paper in order to obtain an 8x8 table divided into 64 unit squares?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

What is the minimum number of squares to be drawn on a paper in order to obtain an $8\times8$ table divided into $64$ unit squares.

Notes:

-The squares to be drawn can be of any size.

-There will be no drawings outside the table.

http://www.puzzleup.com/2015/puzzle/?16

Comment: Although the "competition" has no rewards other than bragging rights, I am voting to close this as being from an ongoing competition.  [According to PuzzleUp's rules page](http://www.puzzleup.com/2015/rules/), submission is still open for this and earlier problems for this year.  Continue thinking about the problem on your own for another few more weeks for when this year's competition ends and they will post solutions themselves.

Comment: I second the previous comment.  It's a good question, but let's wait until the contest period has ended.

Comment: Contest ended today.

Answer (score 1):

Puzzleup answer is $14$.

But solution for $15$ is:

Start out with a blank $8*8$ square ($1$ square) that can house $64$ small squares. Starting in the top-left corner, draw a $1*1$ square. Then, draw a $2*2$ in that same corner overlapping the first. Repeat this until you have the $7*7$ square.

Then, start at the bottom right with the same process. Draw a $1*1$, a $2*2$, etc. You only have to draw $7$ this time again. Now you've got a $64$ square unit grid made of exactly $15$ squares $(1+7+7)$.

An accompanying visual:
[image]

Comment: Nice. Proof that it is correct: You just prove that every *line* on the chessboard is drawn. Decompose the line (row or column) into two parts, based on intersection with diagonal. The top (or left) part is covered with the "top-left" process, the bottom (or right) part is covered with the "bottom right" process. Unfortunately, PuzzleUp will not be very happy! ... P.s. of course this is not proof of the minimum...