# How can we draw $14$ squares to obtain an $8 \times 8$ table divided into $64$ unit squares?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, optimization, algorithms, recreational-mathematics

How can we draw $14$ squares to obtain an $8\times8$ table divided into $64$ unit squares?

Notes:

-The squares to be drawn can be of any size.

-There will be no drawings outside the table.

Comment: Is the outer edge of the table already drawn? If not I don't think it can be done in less than 15.

Comment: The number $14$ makes me think of three sets of four, one in each quadrant or one along each side, plus two centered squares.

Comment: @Jorik, The outer edge is not drawn.

Comment: May I request you to add a part 2 to this question? The part 2 being as follows - How can one analytically model this problem to find the formula for the least number of squares needed to construct a chess board of dimensions n x n?

Comment: This is (or was) part of a live contest:  http://www.puzzleup.com/2015/puzzle/?16  Has that contest ended?

Comment: @DeepakGupta For even $n = 2m$, the least number of squares is $2n-2$. The $2n-2$ squares can be chosen as $[0,k]^2$ and $[k,n]^2$ for $0 < k < n$ excluding $k = m$ plus $[0,m]\times[m,2m]$ and $[m,2m]\times[0,m]$.

Comment: @achillehui I found the same just now. You can also make it work for odd $n$. I can prove you can't do it with less either. I'll post an answer.

Comment: @achillehui  Ah, good.  This earlier post (from the same writer) is relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1578664/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-squares-to-be-drawn-on-a-paper-in-order-to-obtain

Comment: @lulu Yeah this question is seems to be a straight up duplicate. Should we mark it as such? I could post my answer on that question.

Comment: @lulu The contest ended.

Comment: @Jorik  Well, the other one got put on hold (as the contest was live).  If the contest is done, maybe the best thing is to lift the hold?

Comment: @Guest47812  So I see, thanks.  If we can, I'd say it was better to lift the hold on the original post (which has some good work on it).  Failing that, maybe it's useful to link to the older question here.

Comment: Oh I found an oversight in my proof. I'll have to think about it a bit more.

Comment: @Jorik, the lower bound that one need $2n-2$ squares is easy. There are $4n-4$ edges perpendicular to the table boundary and any square we allowed to use cover at most $2$ such edges.

Comment: @achillehui Ah of course you are correct. I was looking at the horizontal lines only but missed an edge case there.

Comment: @achillehui That was a very elegant way to prove minimality. Thanks a lot. Any non-dagrammatic way of modeling the question? For example, using combinatorics?

Comment: @achillehui I did not understand the last part of your answer - " excluding $k=m$ plus $[0,m]\times[m,2m]$ and $[m,2m]\times[0,m]$"

Comment: @DeepakGupta Start from the $2n-2$ squares $[0,k]^2, [k,n]^2$ for $0 < k < n$, it cover all but two of the squares. The two unit squares at the corners: $[n-1,n]\times [0,1]$ and $[0,1]\times [n-1,n]$. Instead of wasting one more square, one can replace the two squares of side $4$ (i.e. replace $[0,m]^2$ and $[m,n]^2$ by $[0,m]\times [m,n]$ and $[m,n]\times [0,m]$ ) to finish the job.

Comment: That "gotcha!" feeling :) Thanks. Though I still find it hard to interpret your notation that you use for representing the two corner unit squares (top left) and (bottom right). @Jorik's diagrams helped.

Answer (score 8):

The comments on the question pretty much contain all the information you need about this question. I figured I'd add some pretty pictures. In general if $n\geq 4$ then you can draw $2(n-1)$ squares to end up with an $n\times n$ grid of squares and you can't do it with less.

For even $n$ the solution looks like this:[image]

For odd $n$ the solution looks like this:[image]