# What is the minimum number of squares needed to produce an $ n \times n $ grid?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the minimum number of squares that one needs to draw on a white sheet in order to obtain a complete grid with $ n $ squares on a side?

I know that the answer is $ 2n-1 $, the problem is that I don't know how to prove that this is the least number of squares needed. Thanks.

Notes:

-The squares to be drawn can be of any size.

-There will be no drawings outside the table.

Comment: The fact that $1+3+\cdots+(2n-1)=n^2$ gives a construction but I don't have a clue how it can imply minimality.

Comment: @lhf: What construction do you have in mind?

Comment: @joriki, see my answer.

Comment: For $n \ge 4$, the minimum number is $2n-2$. For construction, see this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1580818/59379).

Answer (score 1):

For a proof that $2n-1$ squares suffice,
apply the construction below twice at opposite vertices of a square.
This is based on the fact that $1+3+\cdots+(2n-1)=n^2$.

I don't know how this can imply minimality, though.

[image]

(image from http://www.9math.com/book/sum-first-n-odd-natural-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how to prove that $2n-1$ are required, but here's a proof that $2n-2$ are required. A square can cover at most $2$ of the segments incident on the borders, since otherwise it would have to cover two opposite ones and thus would extend beyond the boundary. There are $4(n-1)$ such segments, so we need at least $2(n-1)$ squares to cover them.

*P.S.*: achille hui's comment and link under the question show that $2n-2$ actually suffice for $n\ge4$.

Comment: What do you mean by 'segments incident'?

Comment: @A.Rober: Adjoining, meeting the border -- every internal horizontal or vertical line meets the border at two places, and I'm referring to the one-unit internal segments right next to the border.